# $p\mid F_n$ show the following is true if ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p \mid F_n$ for $n > 1$, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{n+1}}$.

Fermat numbers $F_n$ are of the form $F_n=2^{2^n} +1$. So $p\mid 2^{2^n} +1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{2^{n}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$. Squaring  both sides, $2^{2{^n}} \times 2^{2^{n}} \equiv 1\pmod p$ and hence $2^{2 \times 2^{n}}\equiv 1\pmod p$. Hence, we conclude that the order of 2 mod p divides $2^{n+1}$ but does not divide $2^{n}$, and hence is equal to $2^{n+1}$.  By the theorem of Lagrange applied in the unit group mod p, $2^{n+1}$ divides $p-1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod p$$

So what is the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $p$?

Comment: p-1 ?? @ThomaAndrewes I get what you mean but why mod $2^{n+1}$ and not $2^n$

Comment: Well, the order must divide $p−1$, but that is not the order of $2$ modulo $p$ in general. Think about it some more.